# Perl - unable to access hash element

Tags: perl, hash

I'm unable to access an element of a hash. The element I want to access is an array. The hash looks like this when dumped with Data::Dumper :

```
$VAR1 = {
      #Lots of vars here
      'ResponsibleID' => '1',
      'DynamicField_AssetMatricole' => [
                                       '2400930             ',
                                       '2901666             ',
                                       '2401940             '
                                     ],
      'ChangeBy' => '19',
      #Lots of other vars here
};
```

Now, when I try to access the nested array, identified by "DynamicField_AssetMatricole", it works well when I use:

```
my $DFname = "DynamicField_AssetMatricole";
$VAR1{$DFname} #WORKS
```

The actual key, though, comes out of mysql, and is stored in another hash structure:

```
$Param{DynamicFieldConfig}->{Name} #this contains "AssetMatricole"
```

Hence I would expect the array being accessible with:

```
$VAR1{'DynamicField_'.$Param{DynamicFieldConfig}->{Name}} #DOES NOT WORK
```

This does not work. We have been troubleshooting a while, trying to understand why the two keys do not match:

```
my $DFname = 'DynamicField_'.$Param{DynamicFieldConfig}->{Name};                                          
my $DFname2 = 'DynamicField_'.'AssetMatricole';    
$VAR1{$DFname} # DOES NOT WORK
$VAR1{$DFname2} # WORKS

if ( $DFname eq $DFname2 ) {                                                                              
    print ERRLOG "STRING MATCH!\n";                                                                       
} else {                                                                                                  
    print ERRLOG "STRING DON'T MATCH!\n";                                                                 
}
```

... this actually prints out "STRING MATCH"

Further investigation: (using [http://metacpan.org/pod/Data::HexDump](http://metacpan.org/pod/Data%3a%3aHexDump) )

```
use Data::HexDump;

my $DFname = 'DynamicField_'.$Param{DynamicFieldConfig}->{Name};                                          
my $DFname2 = 'DynamicField_'.'AssetMatricole';                                                           

my $hd = new Data::HexDump;                                                                               
my $hd2 = new Data::HexDump;                                                                              
$hd->data($DFname);                                                                                       
print ERRLOG $hd->dump;                                                                                   
$hd2->data($DFname2);                                                                                     
print ERRLOG $hd2->dump;
```

Outputs:

```
00000000  44 79 6E 61 6D 69 63 46 - 69 65 6C 64 5F 41 73 73  DynamicField_Ass
00000010  65 74 4D 61 74 72 69 63 - 6F 6C 65                 etMatricole

00000000  44 79 6E 61 6D 69 63 46 - 69 65 6C 64 5F 41 73 73  DynamicField_Ass
00000010  65 74 4D 61 74 72 69 63 - 6F 6C 65                 etMatricole
```

meaning that the two string are actually the same !

Background: the application is being run under mod_perl. Apache and mysql (with all its dbs and tables) are set to UTF8.

Has anyone a clue where we could look into ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You omitted what works and doesn't work!?! And said it works with some non-existent variable?!?! (`%VAR1` instead of `$VAR1`) How can we find the problem, if you don't even show the code that gives the problem!?

Comment: `$VAR1{'AssetMatricole'.$Param{DynamicFieldConfig}->{Name}} #DOES NOT WORK` - sure, the string should have been `DynamicField_`.

Comment: Could be a problem with accessing a magical var. Try stringyfing the var that scalar that gives a problem (`"".$foo->{...}`)

Comment: @choroba, based on later statments, that seems to the a be a typo, but the post is full of such issues, which makes every single claim questionable.

Comment: @choroba, I corrected the typo. Thanks.

Comment: @ikegami, could you post an example of your solution? thanks

Comment: Enabling strictures (`use strict;`) would tell if you're trying to access undefined variable (it's common to write `$VAR{key}` instead of `$VAR->{key}`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Sciolto said:

> I had the use strict; use warnings; defined in the script, and I actually get the errors (like Global symbol "%v" requires explicit package name at) only when I try to access the element with ->, like so: $VAR1->{
>
> %VAR1 is a true hash, and %Param is a hash reference.

Then try

```
$VAR1{'DynamicField_'.$Param->{DynamicFieldConfig}{Name}}
```

Mind the `->` after `$Param` as it is not a hash, but a reference to a hash!

I tried these steps:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my %v = ( X_Y => [ 1, 2, 3 ]);
my $Prm = { test => { Name => "Y" }};

print exists $v{X_Y} ? "found\n" : "none\n";

print "*", $Prm->{test}, "\n";
print "*", $Prm->{test}->{Name}, "\n";
print "*", $Prm->{test}{Name}, "\n";
print "*", $v{"X_".$Prm->{test}->{Name}}, "\n";
print "*", $v{"X_".$Prm->{test}{Name}}, "\n";
print "*", $v{X_Y}, "\n";
```

Output:

```
found
*HASH(0x8006c020)
*Y
*Y
*ARRAY(0x8002bd08)
*ARRAY(0x8002bd08)
*ARRAY(0x8002bd08)
```

At the end I understood the problem! I always define `use strict; use warnings;` at the beginning of the script. So I did not understand why there is not error message when `$Prm{X_Y}` is used. It is defined automatically!

Start the perl code like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
```

and You will have a lot of error messages like this:

```
Global symbol "%Prm" requires explicit package name at ./q.pl line 11.
```

as only $Prm hash reference is defined!

Sciolto said:

> What I do next is to refer to that array and put the values in another hash: my %TicketValues; %TicketValues = map {$_ => $*} $LinkTicketInfo{'DynamicField*'.$Param{DynamicFieldConfig}{Name}}

Try:

```
my %TicketValues = map {$_ => $_} @{$LinkTicketInfo{'DynamicField_'.$Param->{DynamicFieldConfig}{Name}}};
```

Comment: But the key should start with `DynamicField`.

Comment: @TrueY, yes I am sure it works, since applied to my case, `$v{X_Y}` refers to a key, represented by the `DynamicField_AssetMatricole` string.

Comment: @user2365717: Ok, try to add `->` after `$VAR1`. It should work. See my example and You can see, that `$v{X_Y}` does not return a value, but `$v->{X_Y}` does.

Comment: @TrueY,  `$VAR1->{'DynamicField_'.$Param{DynamicFieldConfig}->{Name}}` is the first thing I tried. I will try the other examples you've posted.

Comment: @sciolto: Ok, add the `use strict; use warnings;` at the beginning of Your perl script! You will have error if you use `$VAR1{...}` as no `%VAR1` is defined!

Comment: @TrueY, I had the `use strict; use warnings;` defined in the script, and I actually get the errors (like `Global symbol "%v" requires explicit package name at`) only when I try to access the element with `->`, like so: 
`$VAR1->{'DynamicField_'.$Param{DynamicFieldConfig}->{Name}}`

Comment: @sciolto: Ok, so You have defined the variable as `my %VAR1;`, not like it is dumped? `VAR1` and `Param` are defined as `%VAR1` and `%Param`, aren't they?

Comment: @TrueY, `%VAR1` is a true hash, and `%Param` is a hash reference. I defined the first myself. and I get the second as a parameter of the function I'm editing.

Comment: @sciolto: Ok, so You have `my %VAR1; my $Param`. Then `$Param{DynamicFieldConfig}->{Name}` is wrong. Use `$Param->{DynamicFieldConfig}{Name}` and always use `use strict; use warnings;`!

Comment: @TrueY, we're getting closer to a solution I think. But still it's not complete: now I refer to the array element of the hash like this: `$VAR1{'DynamicField_'.$Param{DynamicFieldConfig}{Name}}`, which Dumps so: `$VAR = [
          '2400930             ',
          '2901666             ',
          '2401940             '
        ];`

What I do next is to refer to that array and put the values in another hash:

`my %TicketValues;
    %TicketValues = map {$_ => $_}  $LinkTicketInfo{'DynamicField_'.$Param{DynamicFieldConfig}{Name}}`

Comment: @sciolto: use `@{$array_ref}`. For example see the end of my answer. I think it is pointless to create a hash like this : `$_ => $_`. Use `$_ => 1` instead. If `$Param` is a reference to hash then `$Param{key}` will not work.

Comment: @TrueY, ok I now map the hash like `$_ => $_`, the thing is no matter how deep I look into the data structure I always get an array as first element mapped by `$_`: 

`%TicketValues = map {$_} $LinkTicketInfo{'DynamicField_'.$Param{DynamicFieldConfig}{Name}}`. Dumping the new hash, I get: 
`$VAR1 = {
          'ARRAY(0xc9187a8)' => 1
        };`

I think we're really close !

Comment: @sciolto: As I said put the array reference to `@{..}`. I added at the end of my answer: `my %TicketValues = map {$_ => 1} @{$LinkTicketInfo{'DynamicField_'.$Param->{DynamicFieldConfig}{Name}}};`

Comment: @TrueY, sadly all the excitement has gone, because `my %TicketValues = map {$_} @{ $LinkTicketInfo{'DynamicField_'.$Param{DynamicFieldConfig}{Name}} };` just has the same behavior, meaning white page and no particular errors in the apache logs. Also, I can't reproduce this easily in a standalone script. Your answer works per-se, although not when applied to my case. I think the question is answered correctly. At least I learned more about dealing with hashes .. THANKS !

Comment: @sciolto: the `map {$_}` is not correct! It will not make a proper hash! Try `map {$_ => 1}` instead! I still do not understand how `Param{...}` works if it is defined as ref to hash! If You got `$VAR1 = { 'ARRAY(0xc9187a8)' => 1 };` before then using `@{...}` had to work!